# Decode Base 64 in Array

Tags: php, arrays, base64

im trying to save a base64 image into the webserver from a post request, currently my array looks like this.

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [storename] => test
            [notes] => test
            [image] => data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4........to long
```

When i try to update my code to allow for decode and save all i get echo from image is a number.

**PHP**

```
            $random = md5(rand());
            $nonerejected[] = array(
                'id' => $data['id'],
                'storename' => $data['storename'],
                'notes' => $data['notes'],
                'image' => $data['image'] == "" ? "" : file_put_contents(''.$random.'.JPG',base64_decode($data['image'])), 

            );
```

**Array output**

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 0
        [storename] => test
        [notes] => test
        [image] => 503331
    )
```

)

Any ideas guys?

Comment: base64_decode() expects ONLY base64 data. the data uri stuff isn't part of the b64 data and will corrupt the decoded string.

Comment: How can i remove this?

Comment: It's just a string. use substr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data:image/jpeg;base64,` bit isn't base64, so base64 can't really do anything with it. You'll have to strip this off in order to store your file.

Comment: what do i use to strip it off?

Comment: Hacky method: `$image = array_pop(explode(',base64,', $data['image'], 2));`

Comment: Excuse me? I don't understand your question?

Comment: Sorry I added to my code and get   : Runtime Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Comment: Oh, that's something you can choose to ignore. If you want to solve it: `$parts = explode(',base64,', $data['image'], 2); $image = array_pop($parts);`

Comment: Ok all fixed but still densest save :(